# Children of a FrameworkElement are not rendered

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement

I created a custom FrameworkElement and added multiple Children, which are also FrameworkElements, via the AddLogicalChild method.

But the children are not rendered, the OnRender method isn't even invoked. Just as the methods MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride.

I did some research but I got stuck, maybe somebody can help me out.

Here are the two classes that I made. In the ChildElement class I set a breakpoint in every method. But none if the methods is invoked except the ctor.

```
public class HostElement : FrameworkElement
{
    public HostElement()
    {
        ChildElement ce;
        Int32 rows = 5;
        Int32 cols = 5;

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                ce = new ChildElement();

                this.AddLogicalChild(ce);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, null, new Rect(0, 0, this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight));
    }
}

public class ChildElement : FrameworkElement
{
    public ChildElement()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);
    }
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: try calling UpdateLayout on the FrameworkElement

Comment: Can we see some code? Try isolating the problem by reducing your code to the bare minimum needed to demonstrate the issue. If the solution doesn't jump out at you, post that reduced code here and we'll much more quickly be able to help you! :)

Comment: The logical children of a `FrameworkElement` are not part of the visual tree. You want an `UIElement` and add to the `Children` collection.

Comment: Why are you doing this in C#? Why not do it in XAML as intended? Seems like it would be a lot more straight forward as well.

Comment: [How to: Create a Custom Panel Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753321(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Clemens Thanks clemens, that was the hint I was looking for. Calling the Arrange method for each child in the ArrangeOverride of the HostElement worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the logical and the visual tree. You want to do this:

```
public class HostElement : Panel
{
    public HostElement()
    {
        ChildElement ce;
        Int32 rows = 5;
        Int32 cols = 5;

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                ce = new ChildElement();

                this.Children.Add(ce);
            }
        }
    }

    // etc...
}
```

[More information about logical vs visual tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456677/concepts-of-visul-tree-and-logical-tree)

Comment: Now you would usually also override MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride.

Comment: @Clemens Depends on what you want to accomplish, but usually yes. At least measure is probably needed.

Comment: Without that the Panel won't show anything. Give it a try.

Comment: Ah, it's probably because the children's `DesiredSize` is (0,0) by default.

Comment: You would at least have to arrange the Children.

Comment: Right, final size is also (0,0). So you need both measure and arrange.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt Thanks for the answer, it is really late now. But tomorrow I will give it a try. Good Night.

Comment: It works with the Panel, but you have to override the ArrangeOverride method and arrange the child elements.